# Write All Data to CSV With For-Loop In Spring-Boot

Tags: spring-boot, csv, spring-batch, opencsv

I have a query in my Spring-Boot project. With this query, I can pull data with limit-offset 100 by 100. After pull it, I want to write all filtered data to CSV. In here actually, I wonder how I can go on.

Repository:

```
public List<Response> filterData(FilterOptions, limit, offset)
{
    sql = "select 
           name, date, sum ... 
           from 
           metadata join report 
           where filters 
           limit 100 , offset ..."
    //native query mapping to Response entity list.
    return responseList.
}
```

Service:

```
public void exportData(FilterOptions, totalRows)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < totalRows; i=i+100)
       {
           data = repository.filterData(filterOptions, limit=100, offset=i);
           writeToCsv(data);
       }
}
```

In here, in service part; How can I handle writeToCsv part? To use Spring-Batch will be useful for my case? Or to use open-csv? Can I implement parallelism in here?

Comment: If you want all data then fetch all data, and show us writeToCsv function details

Comment: You could use the Pagination option to get limited rows for each query. But as Eklavya suggested, it would be best if you fetch all data. You could also use Apache Spark to read the data and write it to CSV.

Comment: @Eklavya to fetch all data(can be millions rows) is not possible for database. I don't have writeToCsv function yet. Actually In here I try to understand how I can handle it.

Comment: @Nikhil in here Pagination is already implemented. No problem about it. I'll check Apache Spark.

Comment: @Sha Use spring batch here is a good tutorial https://www.jackrutorial.com/2018/03/spring-boot-batch-read-from-mysql-database-and-write-into-a-csv-file-tutorial.html

Comment: @Eklavya what do you think about opencsv (https://attacomsian.com/blog/read-write-csv-files-opencsv) Actually, in here to use Spring-Batch; what will be advantages of it?